# facet_zoom with multiple zoom ranges

Tags: ggplot2, ggforce

I am trying to zoom into multiple sections within a plot.

I know that with `facet_zoom` I can zoom into a section of the plot. For example:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(x = Species == "versicolor")
```

[image: facet_zoom on 1 area]

I would however like to zoom into more then 1 area within the same plot. Is this possible?

I tried:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(x = Species == "setosa"|Species == "virginica")
```

but this doesn't work because selection includes the whole range.

[image]

In this simple example I would ideally have two zoomed plots below each other for the two different species.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what specific, you are looking for, but facet_zoom also comes with limit arguments, like xlim, ylim, that you can adjust to zoom in specific regions. like: (this image is zoomed from 2 - 4 on x-axis)

```
iris %>% ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()+ theme_bw() +
  facet_zoom(xlim = c(2,4))
```

[image]